# Magento Reindex Error catalogsearch

Tags: reindex, magento-1.9.2.1

I have this error during reindex.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 18000 seconds exceeded in .../app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 98 Segmentation fault
```

All reindex procedures are working fine but error only for catalogsearch_fulltext.

Magento version 1.9.2.1. In this moment I cannot upgrade version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do reindex from command line

```
 php -f /Mageto_root/shell/indexer.php reindex
```

Comment: yes i do reindex from command line...

Comment: @Franco So what is the problem now ?

Comment: the problem is the same.. I have 210.000 products and do reindex always from command line